# How to count employees per hour working in between hours?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to count employees per hour working in between intime and outtime hours.
I have below table format with intime,outtime of employee .

My Table :

```
emp_reader_id   att_date         in_time                    out_time         Shift_In_Time   Shift_Out_Time
      111      2020-03-01   2020-03-01 08:55:24.000 2020-03-01 10:26:56.000  09:00:00.0000000   10:30:00.0000000
      112      2020-03-01   2020-03-01 08:45:49.000 2020-03-01 11:36:14.000  09:00:00.0000000   11:30:00.0000000
      113      2020-03-01   2020-03-01 10:58:19.000 2020-03-01 13:36:31.000  09:00:00.0000000   12:00:00.0000000
```

Need to count the employee in the below format.

Expected Output:

```
Period  Working Employee Count
0 - 1             0
1 - 2             0
2 - 3             0
3 - 4             0
4 - 5             0
5 - 6             0
6 - 7             0
7 - 8             0
8 - 9             2
9 - 10            2
10 - 11           3
11 - 12           2
12 - 13           1
13 - 14           1
14 - 15           0
15 - 16           0
16 - 17           0
17 - 18           0
18 - 19           0
19 - 20           0
20 - 21           0
21 - 22           0
22 - 23           0
23 - 0            0
```

I tried with below query with my raw data , but it will not work i need from  above table

```
SELECT 
(DATENAME(hour,  C.DT) + ' - ' + DATENAME(hour, DATEADD(hour, 2, C.DT))) as PERIOD,
Count(C.EVENTID) as Emp_Work_On_Time
FROM 
  trnevents C
WHERE convert(varchar(50),C.DT,23) ='2020-03-01' 
GROUP BY (DATENAME(hour, C.DT) + ' - ' +
          DATENAME(hour, DATEADD(hour, 2, C.DT)))
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: hi can you share the scripts for create table, inserts etc

Comment: @Jens i with raw table but it not get proper solution. it show only punches count which is on that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to have a list of hours (0 to 23) and then left join to your table.

The following query uses recursive cte to generate that list. You may also use `VALUES` constructor or `TALLY` table. Which will gives same effect

```
; with hours as
(
    select hour = 0
    union all
    select hour = hour + 1
    from hours
    where hour < 23
)
select convert(varchar(2), h.hour) + ' - ' + convert(varchar(2), (h.hour + 1) % 24) as [Period],
       count(t.emp_reader_id) as [Working Employee Count]
from   hours h
       left join timesheet t on h.hour >= datepart(hour, in_time)
                            and h.hour <= datepart(hour, out_time)
group by h.hour
```

Demo : [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7641838aae2a02623be1ded456fd8a9e)

Answer (score -1):

Hope that might help but take a look how shift in and shift out are in the code... seems to me its automatic so it could have all you need

```
  SELECT COUNT(Idemp) from aaShiftCountEmp WHERE in_time<'2020-03-01 09:00:00.000' AND out_time>'2020-03-01 10:00:00.000'
```

this is just example for 9h to 10h but u can make it auto,

btw are u sure that this shoul not show SHIFT ppl cOUNT? i mean u sure 0-1, 1-2 instead of 0-1.30, 1.30-3?? etc?